# Blender ascii fbx adds a Armature bone before root bone UE4

Tags: modeling, mesh, armature, bones

I am using blender 2.73a.

I rig a mesh with a armature and export it using FBX 6.1 ASCII exporter. However when I import it in UE4 there is a another bone named 'Armature' before root bone!
This happens with every mesh-armature pair. This is undesirable as it shifts the origin of the mesh (Which is root bone in UE4)

[image]

Comment: Please note FBX 6.1 ASCII exporter is no more maintained and considered deprecated… Would advise to use 7.4 binary one, but it also has major issues with UE4 currently (regarding bones’ animations).

Comment: yeah so blender is a no go for UE4 as far as animation is concerned

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of "fixs" for this problem. For me, this one do the trick Blender (2.83 y UE 4.20):

"As things stand right now, the importer for fbx is effectively patched (a nice word for hacked) to allow as exception for Blender made fbx files if the name of the root node is 'Armature'."

[image]

Source: [https://forums.unrealengine.com/deve...blender-export​](https://forums.unrealengine.com/deve...blender-export%E2%80%8B)

Answer (score 1):

Had this same problem and spent a day trying to work it out. Reverted back to Blender 2.74 and export with FBX 7.4 binary and it worked fine.

For some reason Blender 2.75 and 2.76 add this bone, which means enabling root motion in Unreal Engine does nothing. This sucks because replacing a skeleton in Unreal when you have heaps of animations and montages is annoying. Really hope this gets fixed.